# gnuplot additional parameter to X axis

Tags: gnuplot

I wonder how I can add a parameter to every X parameter. Like on the picture, where every X parameter has an additional parameter.

[image]

I run gnuplot with the following command

```
gnuplot -p -e "reset; set yrange [0:1]; set term png truecolor size 1024,1024; set grid ytics; set grid xtics; set key bottom right; set output 'Recall.png'; set key autotitle columnhead; plot  for [i=2:3] 'Recall' using 1:i with linespoints linecolor i pt 0 ps 3
```

Recall file has the following content

```
train   approach1      approach2
2       0.6      0.07
7       0.64      0.076
9       0.65      0.078
```

I wonder if I can add additional parameter as follows

```
train   approach1      approach2
2(10)       0.6      0.07
7(15)       0.64      0.076
9(20)       0.65      0.078
```

The actual plotting should be according the real X parameters (2,7,9) an additional parameter is only for visualization and should be printed together with X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take an xtic label from your data file, you can use `using ...:xtic(1)` which would take the value of the first column as xtic label.

The disadvantage might be, that for every value in your data file you'll get an xtic, and no other ones. So, using the data file

```
train   approach1      approach2
2(10)       0.6      0.07
7(15)       0.64      0.076
9(20)       0.65      0.078
```

you could plot with

```
reset
set term png truecolor size 1024,1024
set grid ytics
set grid xtics
set key bottom right
set output 'Recall.png'
set key autotitle columnhead
plot for [i=2:3] 'Recall' using 1:i:xtic(1) with linespoints linecolor i pt 7 ps 3
```

and get

[image]

Note, that this uses the correct x-values only, because gnuplot itself drops the content inside the parenthesis, not being a valid number.

If you want to use different font sizes for the label parts, you could add an additional column which contains the parameter.

Data file `Recall2`

```
train   add       approach1      approach2
2       (10)      0.6       0.07
7       (15)      0.64      0.076
9       (20)      0.65      0.078
```

Now, instead of using `xtic(1)`, you can also construct the string to be used as xticlabel:

```
reset
set term pngcairo truecolor enhance size 1024,1024
set grid ytics
set grid xtics
set key bottom right
set output 'Recall2.png'
set key autotitle columnhead
myxtic(a, b) = sprintf("{%s}{/*1.5 %s}", a, b)
plot for [i=3:4] 'Recall2' using 1:i:xtic(myxtic(strcol(1), strcol(2))) with linespoints linecolor i pt 7 ps 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Many `gnuplot`'s *terminals* provide an `enhanced` option
that mimics the functionality provided by the postscript
terminal, functionality [described here](http://materials.ucsd.edu/doc/ps_guide.pdf).

What you want can be done using an enhanced terminal in conjunction with the `set xtics` command (see `help set xtics` for the correct sintax):

```
gnuplot> set term qt enhanced
gnuplot> set xrange [2:10]
gnuplot> set xtics ('{/=8 3} {/=20 (a)}' 3, '6 (c)' 6)
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Please refer to the link for a complete description of the available commands.

#### Update

To produce automatically the x axis labels, one can use *backticks substitution*, either directly in a gnuplot command file or on the command line, as in the OP approach.

The command line is longish...

```
gnuplot -p -e "reset; set yrange [0:1]; set term png truecolor size 1024,1024; set grid ; set key bottom right; set output 'Recall.png'; set key autotitle columnhead; `awk -f Recall.awk Recall` ; plot  for [i=2:3] 'Recall' using 1:i with linespoints linecolor i pt 0 ps 3"
```

The key point is using an awk script that outputs the appropriate gnuplot command, and here it is the awk script

```
% cat Recall.awk
BEGIN { printf "set xtics (" }
NR>1  { 
    printf (NR==2?"":",")
    printf ("'{/=8 %d} {/=16 (%d)}' %d", $1, $4, $1) }
END   { print ")"}
```

#### Oooops!

I forgot to show the modified format of data file...

```
% cat Recall
train   approach1      approach2 
2       0.6        0.07   10
7       0.64      0.076   15
9       0.65      0.078   20
```

and here it is the product of the previous command line

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem is I still a newbie in gnuplot, I added a code, if you have a chance, can you please take a look at the addendum, and give a hint, how to implement the parameter that I want.

Comment: I've looked at your addendum and no, at the moment I don't know how to set the `xtics` from data content. BTW your approach won't work: I'd start using 4 columns, like  in  `2 0.6 0.07 10`, but I have to think if it is possible to do what you want... If I can come up with a solution, I'll update my answer